# How to fetch the rendered data from jquery pivot table

Tags: jquery, pivot, pivot-table, pivottable.js

I am using pivottable.js of jquery. On drag-and-drop the inputs to the available divs, we get the table rendered simulatenously. So we downloaded the plugin and used "pivotUI loaded from CSV". The problem is how am i suppose to fetch the rendered data to be used further in my d3 visualisation.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yes i have tried  this to fetch the row data $(selector).data("pivotUIOptions").rows

Answer (score 0):

(I'm the author of the PivotTable.js library...)

Have you taken a look at the file here: https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/blob/master/src/d3_renderers.coffee ? This is the only existent D3 visualization based on the Pivot Table.

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: link is now fixed!